# XMLReader read to next sibling of unknown type

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I understand how we can use a code sample like the following..

```
public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("books.xml"))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name ", reader.GetAttribute("Name"));
            } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("book"));
        }
    }
}
```

and this will read every sibling of type "book". So in the xml structure like this one below it would work great..

```
<Section>
       <book Name="Titan Quest 1"/>
       <book Name="Titan Quest 2"/>
       <book Name="Adventure Willy"/>
       <book Name="Mr. G and the Sandman"/>
       <book Name="Terry and Me"/>
</Section>
```

But lets say your siblings are not always of type book.. Inside section, we can have book, cd, dvd, or vhs so the xml may look something like this

```
<Section>
       <cd Name="Titan Quest 1"/>
       <book Name="Titan Quest 2"/>
       <vhs Name="Adventure Willy"/>
       <cd Name="Mr. G and the Sandman"/>
       <dvd Name="Terry and Me"/>
</Section>
```

I want to write a method that will give me the Name attribute regardless of what sibling type it is.. Using the above code I would only get [Titan Quest 2]. Can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code with [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) will get all the values from the attributes:

```
 var document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

 var bookValues = document.XPathSelectElement("Section")
       .Descendants()
       .Select(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value);
```

Or using XmlReader to get all the attribute values:

```
List<String> values = new List<string>();
using (var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    xmlreader.ReadToDescendant("Section");
    while (xmlreader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlreader.IsStartElement())
        {
            values.Add(xmlreader.GetAttribute("Name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the resopnse, however it needs to be done with XmlReader class methods :( Our solution is built off of that

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.  Will work with both type books.  I used a combination of xmlreader and XElement :

Here is my xml

```
<test>
   <Section>
       <book Name="Titan Quest 1"/>
       <book Name="Titan Quest 2"/>
       <book Name="Adventure Willy"/>
       <book Name="Mr. G and the Sandman"/>
       <book Name="Terry and Me"/>
   </Section>
   <Section>
       <cd Name="Titan Quest 1"/>
       <book Name="Titan Quest 2"/>
       <vhs Name="Adventure Willy"/>
       <cd Name="Mr. G and the Sandman"/>
       <dvd Name="Terry and Me"/>
   </Section>
</test>
```

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> books = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME))
            {
                while (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    if (reader.Name != "Section")
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Section");
                    }
                    if (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement section = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> book = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                        books.Add(book);
                        foreach (XElement b in section.Elements())
                        {
                            book.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(b.Name.LocalName, (string)b.Attribute("Name")));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the results

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to post this. I never got around to implementing this solution but it looks great!